# Both is correct? 你认为如何 and 如何你认为

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

你认为如何 - More like a Chinese guy would talk like that.

如何你认为 - Feels like the English sentence. *Like the sentence start with "What", "Which" etc.

So both is correct?

Especially to express:

> What do you think...

Comment: No. The second is wrong.

Comment: 如何? 你认为.  is English  grammar, should use the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. 你认为如何
> 2. 如何你认为

The first is correct but the second is wrong.

However, even with this said, you may hear the second sentence from native speakers in casual conversations. As I mentioned in [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/40467/25227), some people tend to reverse orders while speaking. For example "山东人我是". But don't get me wrong: this sentence is not correct and you should not say the same. However, just don't be surprised if you hear some native speakers make the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In formal text, the first one is correct and the second one is wrong.

But 我认为/你认为 is similar to the 'I think' in English. It can be put anywhere as the speaker feels like it in casual setup.

Answer (score 1):

To express QUESTION type sentence:

你认为如何 is correct.

e.g.
你認為如何才能維持身體健康？

如何你认为, use 為何 instead of 如何 would be better.

e.g.

**为何**你认为維持身體健康很重要？ (correct.)

If you talk to me with 如何你认为, as a native user, I know you are asking a question without any problem.

e.g.

如何你认为他是對的？

如何你认为這個結果沒問題？