# Why do we use 的 at the end of this sentence 你穿这么少，会感冒的?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I'm familiar with some basics of the 的 usage. But what exactly does it do in this sentence?...Thank you in advance! Would welcome any other examples...

Answer (score 2):

When "的" is at the end of a predictive sentence, or statement, it indicates the "certainty" of the prediction or occurrence of the stated event. So, "你会感冒的" is equal to saying "You (**certainly**) will catch a cold".

Here is a related thread that has an excellent answer on this type of sentence structure. ["我一定会去看他的"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/906/why-use-%E7%9A%84-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-such-as-%E6%88%91%E4%B8%80%E5%AE%9A%E6%9C%83%E5%8E%BB%E7%9C%8B%E4%BB%96%E7%9A%84)

Also, on the general uses of "的" - https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%9A%84/453974

Answer (score 2):

的 here is a 语气词(Modal Particle). It's not as strong as the English word "certainly", "really", etc unless you put an emphasis on 的 during speech.

Here is the dictionary definition:

> 用在句末，表示肯定的语气或已然的语气

E.g. 他什么时候走的？

Compare 他什么时候走 with 他什么时候走的. 他什么时候走 means *when will he leave* whilst 他什么时候走的 means *when did he leave*. With 的，it adds that *the fact already takes place.* (已然).

会感冒 vs 会感冒的

的 adds the effect that 感冒 will happen in the future. Compare 衣服穿少了会感冒 and 衣服穿少了会感冒的. Both denotes the same meaning. 衣服穿少了会感冒的 is more conversational in practice. The brief version 衣服穿少了会感冒 is more likely to be used where the neat style is preferred.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me and is useful/informative. But it wouldn't be so useful if I were a beginner student. I think it could be improved by adding some English translations (for the dictionary definition; the terms 语气词, 已然; ...)

Answer (score -2):

你穿这么少，是会感冒的

> You don't wear enough clothes, you are going to get a flu.

你穿这么少，是会感冒 is incomplete sentence.

Comment: 1) your sentence is different from the one in the OP as you have added a 是. 2) Would the sentence in the OP be incomplete without the 的? If so, why? At the moment I'm downvoting this response due to the above issues.

Comment: a proper sentence always need to be edited,  if we do not edit,  why we need a teacher?

Comment: Yes, and? // You haven't addressed the points I raised.